# Match two distinct values from a single column in a joined table

Tags: join, sqlite

I have three tables:

```
class:
class_id
class_name

student:
student_id
student_name

class_schedule:
class_id
student_id
```

I want to select all the classes where studentA and studentB are in the same class using the student names. I can use a subquery to pull all the classes studentA is in, and then from that subset the classes that studentB is in and that works. That being said, it is terribly inefficient. I have tried a number of solutions including joining the same table twice, once for each value I want to find, but always get an empty result set.

For testing and prototyping purposes I am using sqlite, but will reside on DB2 long term.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. If you would like assistance with your question then please provide a [mcve] and if you are actually looking on improving the performance of your query/application, then please read [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/15356) (Meta DBA.SE). Thanks.

Comment: See the fiddle in my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select c.class_id, c.class_name
  From class c, class_schedule cs
  Where c.class_id = cs.class_id
    And cs.student_id in (
          select student_id from student
            where student_name in ('studentA','studentB'))
  Group by c.class_id, c.class_name
  Having count(*) = 2
```

Check it out: [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5imLR5PBr6bg3fy8bX5WAY/0)

Comment: I do not see the information that any column in source table is unique. So `count(*)` is incorrect. PS. WHERE IN instead of JOIN degrades the performance. PPS. Use JOIN instead of cartesian (comma-separated tables list).

Comment: @Akina, there's nothing cartesian in my query.

Comment: `From class c, class_schedule cs` - this is cartesian.

Comment: On its own, perhaps, but you missed "Where c.class_id = cs.class_id".

Comment: No, I see it. But it changes nothing.